# No warning if function parameter type mismatches

Tags: mingw, codeblocks

I am expecting warning message because of type mismatch in function parameters. But I am not getting any warning. I am not even typecasting. I am using latest version of codeblock with MinGW. I have enabled "Enable all common compiler warnings" in compiler settings. I have not created any project, instead directly compiling individual file.

```
void function1(int a, float b)
{
    printf("%d",a);
    printf("%f",b);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a=5;
    float b=12.4522;
    // Do something
    function1(b,a);
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly specify casts for conversions between arithmetic types; the compiler will perform them implicitly (and silently) when required. If you want warnings for the cases you show in your example, you need to explicitly enable `-Wtraditional-conversion` -- neither `-Wall` nor `-Wextra` is sufficient. Note however, that `-Wtraditional-conversion` cannot be used for `C++` compilation -- it is allowed for `C` and `Objective-C` **only**.

Further note that, when compiling your example, I also specified `-pedantic`, which causes the compiler to emit a warning about your (mis)use of `C++` style comments.